# Named query not found for NamedPLSQLStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.1, toplink

I'm trying to use EclipseLink to call a stored procedure (in Oracle database) and when I tried to call I always got the named query not found.

I tried with `entityManager.createNamedQuery`, `createdNamedStoredProcedureQuery`, and `JpaEntityManager` create query methods as well.

My declaration is:

```
@NamedPLSQLStoredProcedureQueries({@NamedPLSQLStoredProcedureQuery( name = "ChangeTheStatusForTheLoadedARTransactions"
                                                                  , procedureName = "OALEDU_LC_API_PKG.DERIVE_CD_DATA"
                                                                  , parameters = {@PLSQLParameter( name = "p_ar_data"
                                                                                                 , direction = Direction.IN
                                                                                                 , databaseType = "OALEDU_LC_API_PKG.T_AR_TYPE" )}  
                                                                   )})
@Embeddable
@Struct( name = "LOADED_AR_TRANSACTIONS"
       , fields = {"INTERFACE_LINE_ATTRIBUTE1, INTERFACE_STATUS, INTERFACE_LINE_ID"})
@PLSQLRecord( name = "OALEDU_LC_API_PKG.T_AR_REC"
            , compatibleType = "OALEDU_LC_API_PKG.T_AR_REC"
            , javaType = LoadedArTransaction.class
            , fields={ @PLSQLParameter(name = "INTERFACE_LINE_ATTRIBUTE1", databaseType = "NUMBERIC_TYPE")
                     , @PLSQLParameter(name = "INTERFACE_STATUS")
                     , @PLSQLParameter(name = "INTERFACE_LINE_ID", databaseType = "NUMBERIC_TYPE")})
public class LoadedArTransaction {...}
```

If somebody has experience with it, and can tell me, what I missed or did wrong, I'll appreciate it!

Comment: Can you include the exact text of the error you're getting?

Comment: Is this class in the persistence unit?  Try adding it to the persistence.xml, and check the Eclipselink logs that it is being processed.

Comment: Yes it is/was in the persistence.xml. 
I cannot include the exact text, because we are change the solution to jdbc call because of time. Once if I try again, I'll let you know!